# Remove the blood on the walls in Splitgate?

Tags: splitgate-arena-warfare

I know there is an option to disable the blood on the players, but there is still blood on the arena walls, which I want to remove.  Is there any way to do this?  Im willing to deal with lower texture quality if that removes it, tho I doubt it does.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can disable blood under the Gameplay tab in the Settings menu but I don't think it works on the arena walls. Everywere I look it just keeps showing this soloution. So try this, if it does not work I don't think there is a way to do this.